# How to fetch n to n-3 data of the same column and populate as a new column on the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to manipulate a data where I want to fetch the old values of the same column and enter as a new column of the same row.
I have a Pandas Dataframe called test_df where I have a column score. Based on the Release date column I want to get the score of previous three version of the current version grouped by the product.

```
Product  Version  score   Release
Android    1       5    September 23, 2008
Android   1.1      7   February 9, 2009
Android   1.5      6   April 27, 2009   
Android   1.6      8   September 15, 2009   
iOS       3.1.3    8   February 2, 2010
iOS       4.2.1    6   November 22, 2010     
iOS       4.2.1    9   May 7, 2012
```

So I want to create a new columns as score1, score2 and score3. Column score1 should have the score of the previous version of the same product and score 2 has the version before last and so on.
If I select n then the new columns should have n-1, n-2, n-3 data

```
   Product  Version  score   Release             score1      score2    score3
    Android    1       5    September 23, 2008   NULL         NULL      NULL
    Android   1.1      7   February 9, 2009      5            NULL      NULL
    Android   1.5      6   April 27, 2009        7             5        NULL
    Android   1.6      8   September 15, 2009    6             7        5               
    iOS       3.1.3    8   February 2, 2010      NULL         NULL      NULL
    iOS       4.2.1    6   November 22, 2010      8           NULL      NULL
    iOS       4.2.1    9   May 7, 2012            6            8        NULL
```

So when I select Product as Android and version as 1.1, should get the score of previous version in a separate column.
Is there anyway we can achieve this in Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but note that since by "`NULL`" you most likely mean `NaN`, that will make your `score1` etc. columns `float`, even if `score` itself are `int`.

Anyway:

```
def trail(g, delays, column='score', defaultval=np.nan):
    for k in delays:
        newcol = f'{column}{k}'
        g[newcol] = defaultval
        g[newcol].values[k:] = g[column].values[:-k]
    return g

df = (
    df
    .sort_values(['Product', 'Release'])
    .groupby('Product')
    .apply(lambda g: trail(g, delays=range(1, 4)))
)
```

With your data:

```
print(df)
   Product Version  score    Release  score1  score2  score3
0  Android       1      5 2008-09-23     NaN     NaN     NaN
1  Android     1.1      7 2009-02-09     5.0     NaN     NaN
2  Android     1.5      6 2009-04-27     7.0     5.0     NaN
3  Android     1.6      8 2009-09-15     6.0     7.0     5.0
4      iOS   3.1.3      8 2010-02-02     NaN     NaN     NaN
5      iOS   4.2.1      6 2010-11-22     8.0     NaN     NaN
6      iOS   4.2.1      9 2012-05-07     6.0     8.0     NaN
```

You can also provide a different default value, e.g. `-1`, which will let your new columns be `int`:

```
print(
    df
    .sort_values(['Product', 'Release'])
    .groupby('Product')
    .apply(lambda g: trail(g, defaultval=-1, delays=range(1, 4)))
)
# output:
   Product Version  score    Release  score1  score2  score3
0  Android       1      5 2008-09-23      -1      -1      -1
1  Android     1.1      7 2009-02-09       5      -1      -1
2  Android     1.5      6 2009-04-27       7       5      -1
3  Android     1.6      8 2009-09-15       6       7       5
4      iOS   3.1.3      8 2010-02-02      -1      -1      -1
5      iOS   4.2.1      6 2010-11-22       8      -1      -1
6      iOS   4.2.1      9 2012-05-07       6       8      -1
```

**Side note**: to put your data in a df, I copied the text of your example (including trailing spaces) and read as csv as follow:

```
txt = """Product  Version  score   Release
Android    1       5    September 23, 2008
Android   1.1      7   February 9, 2009
Android   1.5      6   April 27, 2009   
Android   1.6      8   September 15, 2009   
iOS       3.1.3    8   February 2, 2010
iOS       4.2.1    6   November 22, 2010     
iOS       4.2.1    9   May 7, 2012
"""
txt = '\n'.join([re.sub(' {2,}', '\t', s.strip()) for s in txt.splitlines()])
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep='\t', parse_dates=['Release'])
```